Hinge Joint Object Wraps Rotation Limits
I've created a hinge joint for a notebook cover and a notebook. The notebook cover (which has the hinge joint) has the limits 0 and -200. However after the testing I've done, it looks like when the limit is set past -180 or 180, the notebook cover, instead of slightly bouncing back or resting at -200, wraps back around to 0 degrees and does this loop over and over.
I've tried changing the rigidbody collision detection for both objects, and I've tried changing the notebook's movement type in the XR grab interactable. Neither changed anything. I've attached some screenshots and videos to help visualize the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.
Screenshots:
https://imgur.com/a/Dja1ZKI
Video:
https://streamable.com/fdpcga
